# Uncaught TypeError: $.confirm is not a function

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I want to delete a specific row from db. But it will not work properly and shows an error in my console page. 
Is that the problem of my function?
Or button click?

> (index):393 Uncaught TypeError: $.confirm is not a function
>       at askDelete ((index):393)
>
> (index):393 Uncaught TypeError: $.confirm is not a function
>       at askDelete ((index):393)

```
<a href="javascript:askDelete(<?php echo $list->id;?>);" class="btn btn-info delete_button" role="button">Delete</a>
<button  onClick="askDelete(<?php echo $list->id;?>);" class="delete_action delete_button" >Delete</button>

                                                     </ul>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>


                                                <?php $i++;}?>     

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function askDelete(val){
    $.confirm({
    title: '<h4 class="confirm-title">Delete Format</h4>',
    content: '<p>Do you want to delete the format?</p>',
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            btnClass: 'delete-btn',
            keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
            action: function(){ 
                var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
                table.row($('#program_'+val)).remove().draw(false);
                var site_url = "<?php echo site_url();?>";
                $.ajax({
                url: site_url+'/welcome/delete_sample/'+val,
                type: 'post',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data==1){
                        var msg_type="1";
                        var msg_msg="Sample deleted successfully";
                        set_jnotice(msg_type, msg_msg);             
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                });
            }
        },
        cancel: {
            btnClass: 'delete-cancel',
            action:function () {            
        }   }     
    }
});

}


</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery (first) and then whatever plugin you used in your document?

Comment: No I am not included jQuery.

Comment: If `$.confirm` refers to a plugin depending on jQuey then you have to inlcude jQuery as well. Is it [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)?
Then additionaly to jQuery you might need to include the bootstrap ressources as well

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' error caused in this section --> keys: ['enter', 'shift'],